# New sites should have everyone as members

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, sharepoint-permissions

When I create a new site in Sharepoint Online, the Members and Visitors groups do not include everyone.

How can I set up Sharepoint so that new sites will have "Everyone except external users" as Members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new site, you need to choose "Public" under privacy settings. Then the new site will have "Everyone except external users" as Members. As the below picture shows:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set "Privacy settings: Public" the default instead of "Private"?

Comment: I guess it is not possible to setup Sharepoint like I want. But I find the answer useful anyways.